# writing to text file separated by |

Tags: vb.net

i am working on windows application.i am taking value from my sql database then writing to one .txt file.i have a code like this:

```
 sql = "select * from " & strtablename
            cmd = New SqlCeCommand(sql, CONN)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            ListBox1.Items.Add("Extracting " & strfilename)
            ListBox1.Refresh()
            While (dr.Read())
                sw = New StreamWriter(hht_Memory & "\Export\" & strfilename & ".txt", True)
                prcount = 0
                fvalues = ""
                For I = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
                    If fvalues = "" Then
                        fvalues = IIf(IsDBNull(dr(I)), "", dr(I))
                        fvalues = Trim(Replace(fvalues, "'", ""))
                    Else
                        fvalues = fvalues & ", "
                        fvalues = fvalues & IIf(IsDBNull(dr(I)), "", dr(I))
                        fvalues = Trim(Replace(fvalues, "'", ""))
                    End If
                Next I

                sw.WriteLine(fvalues)
                prcount = prcount + 1
                sw.Close()
```

this is writing to text file.but each value separated by comma.i want to separate each value by **|**.
what the changes i have to make in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
fvalues = fvalues & ", "
```

should be changed to:

```
fvalues = fvalues & "| "
```

Comment: ok sir but i have confused  here if case,i can change in else case

Comment: @jasbacker: Not sure what you're asking. The change I mentioned should do what you have asked in the question.

Comment: it s oke sir..but after importing data from sql to note pad am getting two || after my datetime field? ex: 455|58|MT|1/2/2009 8:19:51 PM||SRC

Comment: @jasbacker: That's because there is one empty field between that datetime field and the next field. The `If` part does that thing. Also note that this is the correct behavior. If you open your file in any application that supports delimited text files (e.g. Excel), you'll need to have some that double pipe sign right there to tell Excel about the end of one field and the beginning of next, so that all values are aligned properly.